# Deploying rails, paperclip error, no such file to load -- cocaine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Using the paperclip-cloudfiles fork of paperclip:

```
gem 'paperclip-cloudfiles', '~>2.3', :require => 'paperclip'
```

Using passenger and I get the following load error: `no such file to load -- cocaine`

Key part of stack trace:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/paperclip-cloudfiles-2.3.10.1/lib/paperclip.rb   43  in `'
```

Paperclip works fine locally on the development server. Haven't been able to find any reference to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: lol.. it seems to be a required file in paperclip from what I've been able to tell.

Comment: On a side note...try and help other's here, your profile shows you've  asked 38 questions and answered 0. Try and be a 'giver' rather than a 'taker'. Everyone out here has other engagements and jobs. You don't need to be an expert to answer questions here, I am not! Just a bit of philosophy, hope you don't mind... ;)

Comment: Just started doing software, mostly a hardware guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]: Downgraded paperclip-cloudfiles to '2.3.8' and it works. Must be a problem with the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I would add

```
gem require 'cocaine'
```

to your Gemfile  then run bundle install again.

Extra credit . . .  add the dependency to the gem itself and send it back to the community at large.

---

Updated: per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762515/paperclip-gem-validation-error-filename-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify) issue, you should specify version 0.3.2 of cocaine or Paperclip will break.  Paperclip currently relies on an older Cocaine API, so specifying the version (0.3.2) in the gemfile in necessary or paperclip won't work.

```
gem "cocaine", "0.3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already run `bundle install` on your production server?

Comment: and also restarted passenger after running `bundle install`.

Comment: Running `sudo bundle install` is silly. Just `bundle install`.

Comment: sorry 'Bigg' bro... ;) Even though it is technically correct, but not necessary infact as bundle install itself asks for a password if it needs to install a gem. Edited the answer. That downvote hurt real bad...;)  why are you so angry....you also had the option of editing the answer.....:P

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the missing cocaine gem by
'gem install cocaine'
and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762515/paperclip-gem-validation-error-filename-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify) issue.  Paperclip currently relies on an older Cocaine API, so specifying the version (0.3.2) in the gemfile in necessary or paperclip won't work.