# paperclip gem validation error - 'filename' is not recognized by the 'identify' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to get the paperclip gem to upload images on my production server (ubuntu 12.0.4, apache2, phusion passenger and rvm) and for each attachment I get three lots of this validation error:

> Img one /tmp/villa-0520121006-4333-hdo9wv.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

ImageMagick is installed properly, as is the libmagickwand-dev package, Rmagick and paperclip.
And I've set the correct command_path to where identify and convert are located in my production.rb config file.

here is my model if it helps:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :img_one, :img_two, :img_three, :img_four, :img_five, :img_six, :price, :title, :description, :location, :beds, :property_type, :agreement_type, :featured  
    has_attached_file :img_one, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }
    has_attached_file :img_two, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }
    has_attached_file :img_three, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }
    has_attached_file :img_four, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }
    has_attached_file :img_five, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }
    has_attached_file :img_six, :styles => { :medium => "420x280>", :mobile => "300x220", :thumb => "100x80>" }


    validates_presence_of :title, :description, :location, :beds, :property_type, :agreement_type, :price
    validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
    validates :beds, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0 }
end
```

I'm really scratching my head with this one and any help or advice would be much appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was apparently caused by the cocaine gem 0.4.0 breaking paperclip (I'm using paperclip 3.2.0).  To fix the issue I reverted back to an older version of that gem by doing:

> gem uninstall cocaine

adding this to gemfile

> gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'

and then bundle installing

> bundle install

[Image file is not recognized by the 'identify' command. (heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750737/image-file-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command-heroku)
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038